# nginx cache. How to define list of urls to cache only?

Tags: caching, nginx

I have big list of urls to cache, for example:

```
http://example.com?a=1&b=1
http://example.com?a=2&b=1
etc...
```

There are no rule to describe these, only by direct listing.
I want my nginx to cache only urls I defined in this list and ignore caching for other GET parameters. Is there a way?

Comment: still looking for an answer to this in 2017! :-/